# Creating project file filters for VS2015+ with premake5?

Tags: premake

In our original solution, we have filters in our projects that allow us to sort files: "*Source Files*", "*Header Files*", etc.

I would like to reproduce this behaviour with **premake 5**. I'm able to create filters for sorting projects using `group "..."` but I'm unable to perform the same task *inside* a project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call you're looking for is [vpaths](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/vpaths):

```
vpaths {
    ["Headers"] = { "**.h", "**.hpp" },
    ["Sources/*"] = {"**.c", "**.cpp"},
    ["Docs"] = "**.md"
}
```